# Property of line integral of vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

I have to prove the following $$ \left| \int_\Gamma F \cdot d\gamma \right| \leq M\cdot l(\Gamma) $$ where $M= \max\{ \|F(x)\|:x\in \Gamma \}$ and $l(\Gamma)$ is the lenght of $\Gamma$.

I was using the hypothesis that if for every $\gamma(t) \in \Gamma,\ F(\gamma(t))$ is in the same direction as the vector $\gamma'(t)$ then we have that $F(\gamma(t)) = \alpha(t)\gamma'(t) $ with $\alpha(t)\geq 0, \forall t$. And then

$$  \int_a^b \alpha(t)\gamma'(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt = \int_a^b \alpha(t) \|\gamma'(t)\|^2 \, dt $$ $$ = \int_a^b (\alpha(t)\| \gamma'(t)\|) \|\gamma'(t)\| \, dt = \int_a^b \|F\| \|\gamma'(t)\| \, dt  $$

Therefore $$ \int_\Gamma F \cdot d\gamma = \int_\Gamma \|F\|\|d\gamma\|$$

From there is very easy to see that $$ \int_\Gamma F \cdot d\gamma \leq M\cdot l(\Gamma) = M\int_a^b \|\gamma'(t)\| \, dt $$

But I don't really know how to prove it for the general case, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Twice you manually inserted space between things like $||a||,$ so that you have $||a||\,||b||,$ but if instead of $||a||$ you wrote $\|a\|,$ then no such manual spacing is needed; you see this: $\|a\|\|b\|,$ coded as `\|a\|\|b\|`. I edited accordingly.